# How to add a class on Ember-bootstrap Modal?

Tags: ember.js, ember-bootstrap

I am using ember-bootstrap modal in which attribute "size" is "xl". xl takes my customized modal size class ".modal-xl". But I have another class 
".modal-full" which adds more size to my modal-xl. How can I add this class="modal-full" on my {{#bs-modal-simple}}

```
.modal-xl {
    @media screen and (min-width: $modal-xl) {
        max-width: calc(#{$modal-xl} - 2rem);
    }
}
// add option to bootstrap modal for full-width option
.modal-full {
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
        max-width: calc(100% - 4rem);
    }
}
```

**Template file**:

```
{{#bs-modal-simple open=abc size="xl" title="Pricing Details" onHidden=(action (mut abc))}}
<table></table>
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

Anyone please help me with this. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh Wow!! This is cool I guess. I just have to pass my ".modal-full in the attribute-size = "xl modal-full"

```
{{#bs-modal-simple open=abc size="xl modal-full" title="Pricing Details" onHidden=(action (mut abc))}}
<table></table>
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

Please feel free to give any other suggestions.

Comment: Please see my answer; for the correct way to pass custom classes to any ember component not just `bs-modal`.

Comment: It seems like my solution is not working due the way `bs-modal` is designed; your answer works; but my answer explains why it does so in detail. please take a look!

Answer (score 2):

I would have expected `classNames` to pass your own class to `bs-modal`. What I mean is; the following should have worked:

`{{#bs-modal-simple open=abc classNames="modal-full" size="xl" title="Pricing Details" onHidden=(action (mut abc))}}`

However; it does not seem to be working due to the following reason: The `classNames` passed to `bs-modal-simple` is not passed down to the actual dialog; that is `bs-modal/dialog`. See the [template](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/addon/templates/components/common/bs-modal-simple.hbs#L9) of `bs-modal-simple`. `classNames` stay on `bs-modal-simple` what is passed to `bs-modal/dialog` is in fact `size`.

See `bs-modal/dialog`'s [template](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/addon/templates/components/common/bs-modal/dialog.hbs#L1) definition; it passes `sizeClass` to the corresponding `div` element.

If you check `bs-modal/dialog`'s [source code](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/addon/components/base/bs-modal/dialog.js#L134); you will see that if a `size` property is passed to the component; then it will be added as class name with the following definition: `modal-${size}`. This means if you do pass `size="xl modal-full"` then you will end up having both `modal-xl` and `modal-full` within the `div` element underneath. So the right way seems like surprisingly passing the `size` attribute like this. However; if you do `size="modal-full xl"` for instance; it will not work.

TLDR; since `size` seems like the only property to pass custom class down to the `div` underneath you need to pass your own class like `size=xl your-class-name`.

Comment: @Sankeerna Reddy I have updated my answer so that you can see why the way you do works.

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely right. When I am passing as size = "xl modal-full" the following behavior is observed. "<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-full">
  <div class="modal-content"></div></div>". Thank you!!